# PlayWS calculate the size of a http call without consuming the stream

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I'm currently using the PlayWS http client which returns an Akka stream. From my understanding, I can consume the stream and turn it into a Byte[] to calculate the size. However, this also consumes the stream and I can't use it anymore. Anyway around this?

Comment: you might be able to retrieve the content-length using the HEAD request method, that's how streams work, you can't know how many elements are there unless you consume them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two different aspects related to the question.

1. You want to know the size of the server response in advance to prepare buffer. Unfortunately there is no guaranteed way to do this. HTTP 1.1 spec explicitly allows transfer mode when the server does not know the size of the response in advance via [chunked transfer encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1). See also quote from [3.3.1.  Transfer-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.1):

> 

A recipient MUST be able to parse the chunked transfer coding
(Section 4.1) because it plays a crucial role in framing messages
when the payload body size is not known in advance.

Section [3.3.3.  Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) specifies how length of a message body is defined and it besides the aforementioned chunked transfer encoding it also contains quite unhelpful

> 7. Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message
>    body length, so the message body length is determined by the
>    number of octets received prior to the server closing the
>    connection.

This is added for backward compatibility and discouraged from usage but is still legally allowed.

Still in many real world scenarios you can use `Content-Length` header field that the server may return. However there is a catch here as well: if `gzip` `Content-Encoding` is used, then `Content-Length` will contain size of the compressed body.

To sum up: in general case you can't get the size of the message body in advance before you fully get the server response i.e. in terms of code perform a blocking call on the response. You may try to use `Content-Length` and it might or might not help in your specific case.

2. You already have a fully downloaded response (or you are OK with blocking on your `StreamedResponse`) and you want to process it by first getting the size and only then processing the actual data. In such case you may first use [getBodyAsBytes](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSResponse.html#getBodyAsBytes--) method which returns `IndexedSeq[Byte]` and thus has `size`, and then convert it into a new `Source` using [Source.single](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#single-T-) which is actually exactly what the default (i.e. non-streaming) implementation of `getBodyAsSource` does.